# GO: manipulating random generated float64

Tags: random, numbers, go, generated

I was wondering if we can specify to the random generator to how many numbers should be generated after the point decimal?

Example of default behaviour:

```
fmt.Println(rand.float64())
```

Would print out the number 0.6046602879796196

Desired behaviour:

```
fmt.Println(rand.float64(4))
```

Would then print out the number 0.6047.

Does this functionality already exist in GO or would I have to implement it myself ?

Thank you!

Comment: No, there's no such function and numbers in Go (as in almost all languages) don't naturallly have decimals (read about IEEE754 floating point format). Generate a random number and then round it to 4 decimals.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like only the string representation is important to you, and the fmt package does provide that for you:

```
fmt.Printf("%1.4f", rand.Float64())
```

So yes, you would still need to wrap this call to specify the number of digits after the decimal point.

```
func RandomDigits(number int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%1." + strconv.Itoa(number) + "f", rand.Float64())
}
```

Comment: This is quite inefficient for something that can be done using math. See [this example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/TxU1PnN4RX).

Comment: I suppose it's less efficient if you run it a bunch of times, but I don't think it would matter under most usages. Additionally, your solution technically can break down: http://play.golang.org/p/7yqDJGfta5

Comment: Yes, if you only run it once it does not matter. It depends on what you want to achieve, if you want to format it for the user then string formatting is the way to go, obviously. In other cases the 'break downs' you showed up do not matter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of such function, however it is easy to implement by yourself ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/zCMvyiAgza)):

```
// Truncate the number x to n decimal places
//
// +- Inf -> +- Inf; NaN -> NaN
func truncate(x float64, n int) float64 {
    return math.Trunc(x * math.Pow(10, float64(n))) * math.Pow(10, -float64(n))
}
```

Shift the number `n` decimal places to the left, truncate decimal places, shift the number `n` places to the right.

In case you want to present your number to the user then you will, at one point, convert the number
to a string. When you do that, you should not use this method and instead use string formatting as pointed
out by [Tyson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21220748/1643939). For example, as floating point numbers are imprecise there might be rounding errors:

```
truncate(0.9405090880450124,3) // 0.9400000000000001
```